# Renderizado de cubo con Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

tengo un problema al crear un cubo basico con Three.js. Al momento de renderizar el cubo, no lo muestra en el navegador, ya probé varias formas de arrmar el script pero no me ha funcionado. Directamente el problema es que no me muestra el cubo, lo raro es que el canvas lo crea correctamente.
Algún consejo?¿
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="/scripts/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
// scene.background = new THREE.Color('skyblue')

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000

);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innnerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'skyblue'});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

var animate = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame( animate )

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
};
animate(); 

    </script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes escrito `window.innnerWidth` con 3 enes cuando seteas el tamaño del render.

Por otro lado te falta agregar algún movimiento para que el cubo se mueva y tenga un sentido la animación. Yo coloqué una rotación

```
cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.2/build/three.module.js';

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
// scene.background = new THREE.Color('skyblue')

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

// AQUI EL ERROR  -----------v   Tienes 3 "nnn"
//renderer.setSize( window.innnerWidth, window.innerHeight);

//ASI debería ser:
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 'skyblue' } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

var animate = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame( animate )
      
    //AGREGAR ROTACIÖN
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
};
animate(); 

</script>

    
</body>
</html>
```